# Server creates phantom <style type="text/css"></style>

Tags: html

I have this problem that is driving me crazy:

When hosted on my server the document prints this code even though it is not on file

```
<style type="text/css"></style>
```

On local it doesn't appear.

How is it happening?

See it in action: http://fine.tv.br/phantom.html

Comment: Doesn't add it for me.  Maybe you have a browser extension adding it in?

Comment: Ditto, I'm not seeing it. Try it with browser extensions disabled (in Chrome, this is as easy as opening an Incognito window).

Comment: I am not seeing it.  What server are you running? What language are you coding in? The question is very vague.

Comment: I don't see it either.

Comment: Disabled all extensions and same happened. Thanks for the negative votes, I forgot that in StackOverflow only people who already knows the answers should ask them.

Comment: As it stands all this question gives us to go on is a link. That's not even enough to work with in the present, but in the future it definitely won't be enough because you'll fix it. Questions need to be free standing, useful to others indenfitely and well enough specified to be answerable.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is generated by the browser, and not by the server. When viewing what actually comes back by the server, you get this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Toca do Bandido</title>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Browsers take all kinds of liberties with your returned markup, and will fix unclosed tags, add missing tags, and normalize the HTML before rendering it.

I suspect you are using the DEV tools in your browser of choice instead of using **"View Source"**